# removing duplicates from string array - using HashSet

Tags: java, string-utils

Im trying to convert a string array with duplicates to string array without duplicates by using hashSet like below.

```
String[] d = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(duplicateList)).toArray(new String[0]);


duplicateList = AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,AD,CP,RR,RR,RR,RR,RR,RR,,,,,,,,,,,
```

When I print d its still the same. Am i missing something?

Note: I do not want to loop through and use contains or equals.

Comment: How are you printing the output array? It would help to show a complete working code.

Comment: im just using sysout d.toString();

Comment: print it as : `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));`

Comment: Works for me. Quick question - is your `duplicateList` an array of those 2-letter strings? Or is it a large string that contains a comma-separated list?

Comment: Its a String of comma seperated list.

Comment: @JNPW No surpize it won't work. You have to get an array first, using `split` as in the asnwer below, for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. That should be it.

`d.addAll(Arrays.asList(duplicateList.split(",")));`